# Image gallery issue. Mouse over/out event not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make this image gallery work on my page. If I make a test page and put all of this code in line in a single file, it works fine. If I separate the CSS and Javascript into their own files (yes, I included both files in the HTML page) the mouse over/out events don't work. I'm clearly missing something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. If someone could help me modify the javascript so that it works, I'd greatly appreciate it! :)

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .imgStyle
        {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            border:3px solid grey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="mainImage" style="border:3px solid grey" 
         src="/Images/Hydrangeas.jpg" height="500px" width="540x"/>
    <br />
    <div id="divId" onclick="changeImageOnClick(event)">
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Jellyfish.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Koala.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Penguins.jpg" />
        <img class="imgStyle" src="/Images/Tulips.jpg" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var images = document.getElementById("divId")
                             .getElementsByTagName("img");

        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        {
            images[i].onmouseover = function ()
            {
                this.style.cursor = 'hand';
                this.style.borderColor = 'red';
            }
            images[i].onmouseout = function ()
            {
                this.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                this.style.borderColor = 'grey';
            }
        }

        function changeImageOnClick(event)
        {
            event = event || window.event;
            var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

            if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG")
            {
                mainImage.src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: include the JS at the end of the file and not the beginning like the CSS then it will work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I want to keep the JS script in a separate file....

Comment: yes and where you include this file in your HTML ?

Comment: take a look to [document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).  I assume you need to wrap your js code in that event.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly worked? One way is to reference the commentor, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work or you edit your question and explain what the problem was. Thank you so much :-)